# How to type B\A like faktor, a quotient group

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

i'm in groups theory, just defined A/B a group quotien and I wanna do the same but with A at top-right and B at bottom-left, here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{faktor} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

 I'm defining something: 

\begin{itemize} 

\item[$-$]$\faktor{G}{H}:=\faktor{G}{\sim}=\text{ set definition}$ 

\item[$-$] what i want %something like B\A
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @egreg I would go with `\diagdown` as far as math is concerned (especially fractions).

Comment: If the interest here is a *symbol* that matches your needs, then this is a duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764)

Comment: @TeXnician I very much dislike the typesetting you showed; since `\backslash` is just the horizontal reflection of `/`, it's the best, in my opinion. Oh, but I see the OP uses `faktor`: not my choice.

Comment: @egreg I agree with you that `faktor` is not very convenient, but if the OP uses it, I just tried to keep that. A minor disadvantage may be that `\backslash` is nearly sheer, whereas `\diagdown` is a more flat solution. Maybe just post an own version with `\backslash`. You already got my vote ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just modified the definition from the source file a bit (it's short enough). That provides the new command `\mfaktor` to achieve your aim.

[image: mfaktor]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{faktor}\usepackage{amsmath}\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\mfaktor}[3][]
{
   { \mathpalette{\mfaktor@impl@}{{#1}{#2}{#3}} }
}
\newcommand*{\mfaktor@impl@}[2]{\mfaktor@impl#1#2}
\newcommand*{\mfaktor@impl}[4]{
   \settoheight{\faktor@zaehlerhoehe}{\ensuremath{#1#2{#3}}}%
   \settoheight{\faktor@nennerhoehe}{\ensuremath{#1#2{#4}}}%
      \raisebox{-0.5\faktor@zaehlerhoehe}{\ensuremath{#1#2{#3}}}%
      \mkern-4mu\diagdown\mkern-5mu%
      \raisebox{0.5\faktor@nennerhoehe}{\ensuremath{#1#2{#4}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

I'm defining something: \begin{itemize} \item[$-$]$\faktor{G}{H}:=\faktor{G}{\sim}=\text{ set definition}$ \item[$-$] what i want something like B\ A \end{itemize}

$\mfaktor{B}{A}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks man! exactly what I wanted, thank you for your help, learned so much

Answer (score 3):

What about this simple solution?

I've also substituted `:=` for `\coloneqq` of `mathtools` package.

You can adjust the kerning as you like.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document} 
With standard negative space as kerning:

\begin{itemize}[label=$-$] 
    \item $^{G}\!/\!_{H}\coloneqq {}^{G}\!/\!_{\sim} = \text{set definition}$ 
    \item $_{B}\!\backslash\!^{A}$
\end{itemize} 

With customized kerning (I think it's the best of the three):

\begin{itemize}[label=$-$] 
    \item $^{G}\mkern-2mu/\mkern-2mu_{H}\coloneqq {}^{G}\mkern-2mu/\mkern-2mu_{\sim} = \text{set definition}$ 
    \item $_{B}\mkern-.5mu\backslash\mkern-2mu^{A}$
\end{itemize} 

Without kerning adjustment:

\begin{itemize}[label=$-$] 
    \item $^{G}/_{H}\coloneqq {}^{G}/_{\sim} = \text{set definition}$ 
    \item $_{B}\backslash^{A}$
\end{itemize} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution, far too simple to think about it (if there's a package with some source code) `;)` But I think both (yours and mine) solutions have very bad kerning concerning the "B".

Comment: Much better now. That should be the accepted solution. But it's at least great for reference. It's a pity I can only give one upvote.

Comment: @TeXnician Thank you! But it's a beginner's solution, I'm not able to create a `\DeclareRobustCommand` as you have done...

Comment: Just for protocol: You would have been able, since I just copied the definition from the package source file and changed `\diagup` to `\diagdown` (as well as swapped `\mkern`). But in the most cases the beginner solutions are most understandable.